# How do I stop the spatter?

Tags: frying, stove

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anyway to avoid grease splatter?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8845/anyway-to-avoid-grease-splatter)

I am trying to work on using my stove more often, since I have been told that the oven can dry out foods easier.  I was cooking some delicious hot Italian sausage last night, and I noticed something.  After the food was done cooking, there was a thin layer of grease on my stove and on the floor in front of the oven.  How can I stop grease from spattering out of my pan?