# How to fry meat without spattering oil?

Tags: frying

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to avoid grease splatter?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8845/is-there-any-way-to-avoid-grease-splatter)

Tonight I cooked dinner, which involved sausages for me, and chicken drumsticks for my partner. The sausages went great, then I proceeded to add some more oil and start the chicken.

This is where my pain started. Soon after, the juices from the meat started coming out and caused the oil to spatter all over my arm. I'm only guessing that this is the cause, but it did seem related. I'm now sporting some minor oil burns and wondering if there's any way to reduce the spattering caused by the juices in the meat when cooking this way, as we both enjoy the taste.

Comment: Do you have a lid on that pan?

Comment: @Mien: No lid. Our frying pan doesn't have one.

Comment: @hobodave This is specifically with chicken, not potato chips. Should I edit title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the above suggestions would get rid of the oil splatter problem, they would also result in overcooked meat with a soggy exterior, as all the water created during frying (for example, chicken releases a lot of juice) would remain in the pan and steam the meat instead of frying it.

Your best bet is to get something called a splatter screen. I've seen one at [ikea](http://www.ikea.com/au/en/catalog/products/10165849/)

[image]

, and at walmart, and I would assume kitchen supply stores would carry it too. A splatter screen is basically a fine metal mesh lid with a handle that fits over a variety of pans/pots and while it allows the steam to escape it also prevents the oil from splattering everywhere by catching in it the fine mesh. The best $10 you'll ever spend.

Comment: damn! Had one of these and never knew what it was

Answer (score 2):

Thick chicken portions like legs should be cooked with a lid on. Any lid, doesn't have to fit perfectly. Use a medium-low heat

The main reason is that you should increase the heat all around the chicken (like a mini oven) otherwise you will burn bottom surface before the inside is fully cooked

This also stops the splatters

Make sure the lid it not on fully, so excess steam can escape, hence a slight off size lid if fine. For a tight fitting lid just leave a fork or similar sticking out of the pan to leave a gap for the lid

For an extra crispy finish remove the lid and turn the heat up a bit for the last 5 or so minutes. The entire cooking process should take at least 30 minutes

Comment: Should I be cooking it on a low/er heat as well, or is the lid keeping the heat in enough?

Comment: Legs and thighs are slightly tougher cuts, so they do benefit from a lower, slower cook than the breasts, yes.

Comment: +1 but I find it immensely easier to sear in the pan and then transfer to the oven

Comment: @rfusca always better, other than this uses a huge amount of energy. Great if you are cooking a few kilos at once!

Comment: @TFD - I use my countertop convection oven - so its more energy efficient and I tend to cook for several people at a time.

Comment: @rfusca Interesting idea. Does that give the same effect as a full oven? How is cleaning it like?

Comment: @TFD - Ya, its totally fine for stuff like that.  We rarely, like once a month or less, use the big oven.  Its really easy to clean, the crumb tray slides out, and then after something greasy or such, we just pull the racks out and give it a wipe.  We've got ours at eye level, so its *really really* nice to use.

Comment: @rfusca Any brand/feature recommendations?

Comment: @TFD - There's a Breville thats supposed to be phenomenal however its been out of our price range.  Its universally accepted as the best.  We've had good luck with Oster - we just got http://www.walmart.com/ip/Oster-Extra-Large-Convection-Toaster-Oven/13729291 this one and *LOVE IT*.  Features - we like the digital a lot better.  Obviously convection.  The more expensive ones tend to be better insulated.  And we like the ones with a curved back that let you slide a pizza in.  The one we just got, works great with the 10inch Lodge griddle for pizza.  Pop in chat if you want and we can discuss.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you have to cover your fry pan. Besides spattering your arm it also make a mess of the stove. Since you mention the pan doesn't come with a lid, you can cover it with a piece of **aluminum foil**.  You do not have to wrap it, just casually cover it sufficient - keep glossy side up and spatter oil will stick onto the dull side of the aluminum foil and not easily nucleates and drip.

I would also soak up excess juice with kitchen roll since too much of them may end up dry sticking to the pan.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of preventing spattering is by coating the chicken in batter or flour.